# How is Clash of Clans Builder Base Versus Battle Matchmaking Determined?

Tags: clash-of-clans, clash-of-clans-builder-base

For Clash of Clans Builder Base "Versus Battles", what criteria is used for automatic selection of opponents during PvP matchmaking? Is it based on your the Builder Hall level, number of trophies, number of buildings, building weights, a combination of these, or something else entirely?

Most of the opponents that I've been paired with over the past 60 or so battles appear to have similar BH levels, but the number of buildings and upgrades they have seem to vary quite a bit.

*(I'm wondering because it could affect if/when to upgrade my Builder Hall.)*

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it seems to be trophy levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's trophy level. 10/10 of my last versus battles were against a builder hall above mine (annoying). But all were within +/- 30 of my trophy level.